# How does web (axios) cache works?

Tags: django, caching, axios

When server caches a page, I thought it worked like this, but apparently I'm wrong.

- server stores http response contents in a cache-store with a key (that's generated for the endpoint)
- one could create separate cache key for certain aspects of requests (such as user language)
- when there's a request for the same key, and it's stored in cache-store (such as redis), webserver returns the cached response instead of recreating the response

I think the above understanding is flawed because,,

- when I hit the endpoint with `axios`, first request is hit on the server, but the second request doesn't even hit the endpoint, it seems `axios` is reusing the previous response it received.
- So, if I clear all cache store between two requests, the second request doesn't get to the request handler (view function in django)
- for http request (browser reload) does work as I described in the above, it hits the web server and gets the cached response.

In django, I'm using  `from django.views.decorators.cache import cache_page`

But the question is more of general working of web response cache

General web caching is explained very well here * https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/http-caching

I guess certain client never reaches out to server when `cache-control timeout` or `expires` is set, and some client does reach out to server..

Comment: I don't know anything about axios but are you sure it isn't caching the response itself?

Comment: it seems it does. I'm perplexed axios behavior is different from a web browser (chrome) 
I searched cache related issues or docs on https://github.com/axios/axios but only few hints suggesting axios doesn't cache stuff. (they list axios-cache-plugin for cache GET request, and my project doesn't have it)